# Rails 4 - Use Script Variable as Button Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui

I am using a jquery ui slider (http://jqueryui.com/slider/) inside my ruby erb code.

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
        range:'min',
        value:<%= @last_change %>,
        min: 0.01,
        max: 98,
        step: 0.01,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#slider-value" ).html( ui.value );
        }
});


$( "#slider-value" ).html(  $('#slider').slider('value') );
```

The challenge is put a button using this value updated, with this script variable #slider-value.
At the moment I can show this variable to on my erb (outside JS) with the following:

`<p>Spinner has a value of <span id="slider-value"></span></p>`

However my question is, how could I use this value on the following button:

`<%= link_to "My Button", {:controller => "my_controller", :action => "my_action", :value => **slider_value_from_js** }%>`

I read and I understand that js is client side and server can't handle client things => many references to use complex ajax, partials and stuff, however I don't think that's the problem here since form requests / buttons always use client inputs and that's just that what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually using a `form` for this task looks like a more suitable solution - make the button a `submit` element and store the slider value in a hidden field.

But in your current code you may just dynamically change the `href` property of the link (the `a` element).

```
<%= link_to "My Button", {controller: "my_controller", action: "my_action", value:'{value_to_be_replaced}' }, class:'theButtonClass'%>
```

And:

```
$('a.theButtonClass').attr('href',
  $('a.theButtonClass').attr('href').replace(
    encodeURIComponent('{value_to_be_replaced}'),
    encodeURIComponent('your_new_value_here')
  )
);
```

Comment: instead of replacing only the {value_to_be_replaced} - that would only work on the first replacement (spinner move), how can I make it to update on any value on the "value" even after the first update? This is working so I already marked the reply as solution!

Comment: @ace you can save the link template somewhere before the first assignment

Comment: I don't understand how I can make it, if anyone can help I would appreciate!

Comment: @ace for example - `$(function(){  $('a.theButtonClass').data('linktemplate', $('a.theButtonClass').attr('href')); });` and then use `$('a.theButtonClass').data('linktemplate')` as a template

Comment: spent last hour trying to adapt your solution (for single change) with this without success, if you can edit previous solution with this it would be great since I am unable to make it. sorry I'm very noob in js..